# Is every positive polynomial the ratio of 2 positive coefficient polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, inequalities

Define $P(x)$ to be positive if $P(x)>0$ for $x>0$.

I can prove that a quadratic positive polynomial is the ratio of 2 polynomials with non negative coefficients, for example $\displaystyle x^2-x+1/3=\frac{x^6+1/27}{x^4+x^3+2/3 x^2+1/3 x+1/9}$, and similarly for every $x^2-x+c$ where $c>1/4$. The full proof is not hard and involves some recursive polynomials related to Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind.

This leads me to wonder

**QUESTION**: in general is it true that $P$ positive $\Leftrightarrow$  $\exists Q,R$ with non-negative coefficients, such that $\displaystyle P=Q/R$?

Comment: There is also a cute way of doing this without using the fundamental theorem of algebra, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1727591/448 . That one has the advantage of generalizing to multivariate polynomials.

Comment: Thank you both for the great comments, pointing to results stronger than what I suspected. The connection with Chebyshev that I mentioned can at least be used to prove a small optimality result: $\exists P$ with degree $\le n$ and both $P$ and $P(x)(x^2-x+c)$ have coefficients $\ge 0 \Leftrightarrow c\ge 1/(2 \cos(\pi/(n+2))^2$.

Comment: Isn't this trivially true because `R = 0*x + 1` is a polynomial with non-negative coefficients, so Q=P, dividing by 1 doesn't change the value?  Or does `1` not count as a polynomial in standard math terminology, since its value doesn't actually vary with `x`?  I assume you *want* to rule that out trivial solution, but I don't know if you need any extra restriction in your definitions.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not sure I follow. $P$ is a "positive" polynomial and **can** have negative coefficients, while $Q$ is a non-zero polynomial with non-negative coefficients. So $R$ can be $1$ but it will only work for those $P$ that already have no negative coefficients. Does that clarify the question?

Comment: Ah, I see now, thanks.  So Q=P / R=1 is a valid solution for some P, but the interesting non-trivial cases to prove are P polynomials that have negative coefficients.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is well-known. It is even known that you may take $R=(1+x)^m$ for large enough $m$. See, for example, [John Scholes's solution to Problem 11 of the 38th IMO 1997 shortlist](https://prase.cz/kalva/short/soln/sh9711.html). Note that by the real fundamental theorem of algebra, the general case reduces to the case $\deg P\leqslant 2$.

Comment: clickable version of your link: https://prase.cz/kalva/short/soln/sh9711.html  (you forgot the `HTTPS://` part when you pasted it: Stack Exchange will make it clickable if you do.)

Comment: @PeterCordes fixed this